# Sending x-csrf-token with axios request (Django/Reactjs)

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to send an x-csrf-token with an axios delete request to my django api. Here is the function:

```
export const deleteTripReport = (tripReport) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(deleteTripReportsPending());
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/reports/${tripReport}`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(deleteTripReportsFulfilled());
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(deleteTripReportsRejected(err));
      })
  }
}
```

I've tried adding

`axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'`

below my import. The django server returns 'Forbidden (CSRF Cookie not set'. I've tried adding headers

```
{headers: {
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "mkTF7lcI4BVl42lJcFzqNbfeVvoVfLSH7e01kznsEQLYFEoWdchL0tuKZ5HeGnOa",
}}
```

with my actual cookie. Then the django server returns OPTIONS instead of DELETE, and the console logs missing 'x-csrf-token'.

I'm running the django server on port 8000 and the react server on 3000 for hot reloads, but I can run build, and both will run on 8000, but currently that is failing as well.

Comment: try ` headers: {"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken},`

Comment: @hannadrehman thanks, that worked